# QRegExp: individual quantifiers can't be non-greedy, but what good alternatives then?

Tags: qt, pcre, regex-greedy, non-greedy, qregexp

I'm trying to write code that appends ending `_my_ending` to the filename, and does not change file extension.

Examples of what I need to get:

```
"test.bmp"            -> "test_my_ending.bmp"
"test.foo.bar.bmp"    -> "test.foo.bar_my_ending.bmp"
"test"                -> "test_my_ending"
```

I have some experience in `PCRE`, and that's trivial task using it. Because of the lack of experience in Qt, initially I wrote the following code:

```
QString new_string = old_string.replace(
      QRegExp("^(.+?)(\\.[^.]+)?$"),
      "\\1_my_ending\\2"
      );
```

This code does not work (no match at all), and then I found in the [docs](http://goo.gl/b6rEa) that

> Non-greedy matching cannot be applied to individual quantifiers, but can be applied to all the quantifiers in the pattern

As you see, in my regexp I tried to reduce greediness of the first quantifier `+` by adding `?` after it. This isn't supported in `QRegExp`.

This is really disappointing for me, and so, I have to write the following ugly but working code:

```
//-- write regexp that matches only filenames with extension
QRegExp r = QRegExp("^(.+)(\\.[^.]+)$");
r.setMinimal(true);

QString new_string;

if (old_string.contains(r)){
   //-- filename contains extension, so, insert ending just before it
   new_string = old_string.replace(r, "\\1_my_ending\\2");
} else {
   //-- filename does not contain extension, so, just append ending
   new_string = old_string + time_add;
}
```

But is there some better solution? I like Qt, but some things that I see in it seem to be discouraging.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I know that `QRegExp` has some different modes than the default mode, namely `QRegExp::RegExp2`. You can switch the mode by calling `r.setPatternSyntax(...)`. The doc says, that RegExp2 introduces "greedy quantifiers".

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help with that task. The only difference of `RegExp2` from `RegExp` is that `RegExp`'s quantifiers that apply to capturing parentheses are more "greedy" than other quantifiers, which is confusing. `RegExp2` fixes that. Thanks for the information, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using QFileInfo? This is shorter than your 'ugly' code:

```
QFileInfo fi(old_string);
QString new_string = fi.completeBaseName() + "_my_ending" 
    + (fi.suffix().isEmpty() ? "" : ".") + fi.suffix();
```